# How are pages called where you have multiple pages on one site and clicking links just scrolls down?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

Sorry for the long title, but I want to build a very small page where the user can click on tabs and the actual content should be shown on one site.

For example, you have one menu at the top of the page and a "page" that should be shown when the user clicks the links in the menu. But instead of reloading a new page everytime, all pages should be put above each other and a click to the link should just scroll to the right position.
Analogous, if the user scrolls, the link of the page he sees should be marked as active.

What are these pages called? And do I need jQuery or can I do this with pure bootstrap?

Comment: I think that you're talking about a Landing Page... you mean a single page site, with a nav bar that when you click on a link it goes to some section of the page?

Comment: Right, and every "page" inside the actual html page should be shown with the full browser height.

Comment: I'm not sure that what you're asking for actually has a formal name, but basic functionality can be achieved by making the hyperlink for the nav button point to the id of the element you want to scroll to so `<a href="#contentB">navButtonB</a>` for example.

Answer (score 2):

You only need bootstrap Scrollspy.

> [Scrollspy](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/scrollspy/)
>   : Automatically update Bootstrap navigation or list group components based on scroll position to indicate which link is currently active in the viewport.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question:

> How are pages called where you have multiple pages on one site and clicking links just scrolls down?

is:

Those are generally called either **"Single-Page Websites"** (where you are dealing with a website) or **"Single-Page Applications"** also abbreviated SPA (where you are dealing with a web application of some kind).

Scrollspy is just a navigation/JavaScript component used for those types of websites to create certain scrolling effects.

To achieve the scrolling effects you described, you can use the following jQuery snippet (adjust the speed as needed):

```js
  //Use smooth scrolling when clicking on navigation
  $('.navbar a').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') ===
      this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') &&
      location.hostname === this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top-topoffset+2
        }, 500); // 500 means 500ms or half a second i.e. time it takes to reach the target
        return false;
      } //target.length
    } //click function
  }); //smooth scrolling
```